# C++ change list while iterating?

Tags: list, for-loop, c++11, stl, iterator

In **C++11** have a list called `jobs`, in which I want to delete all jobs with stopped flag being true, so I wrote:

```
auto job = jobs.begin();
while (job != jobs.end()) {
    if (!job->stopped) {
        job = jobs.erase(job)
    } else {
        ++job;
    }
}
```

But someone took a look at my code and said it's wrong which I doin't understand why?

Comment: `job = jobs.erase(job)` a semicolon is missing here.

Comment: they did not tell you why it is wrong? Maybe they just didnt understand the code

Comment: erasing elements from containers in loops is easily done the wrong way. Yours looks ok.

Comment: Perhaps it's wrong because of reasons we don't see in this code snippet - or perhaps it's "wrong" because it would be an inefficient way of doing it if you are using a `std::vector` (see @PaulMcKenzie's comment below for a better alternative - or [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) if you're using C++20).

Comment: `jobs.erase(std::remove_if(jobs.begin(), jobs.end(), [&](auto& job) { return job.stopped; }), jobs.end());`

Comment: I would personally use a `for` loop instead. to get automatic scoping of `job`, but other than that (and the missing semicolon) your code looks fine. You really need to talk to "someone" and get them to give you more details.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, future viewers of this thread will think you have magic powers 

Comment: @anastaciu :-) I `std::promise` I don't.

Comment: @TedLyngmo pun master badge for you.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ur code doesn't work I get: auto is not allowed in lambda

Comment: `if (!job->stopped)` I would expect `if (job->stopped)` so stopped jobs are removed. Also missing semicolon.

Comment: @john auto is allowed in lambda since [C++14](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#generic-lambdas)

Comment: I am using C++11

Comment: @john Then replace `auto` with `JobEntry`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I made a little modification and got: "Variable 'tmp' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified" my code is: jobs.remove_if( []( const JobEntry &job ) { return waitpid(job.pid,&tmp,WNOHANG)==job.pid; } );

Comment: @john What's your question about that? `tmp` isn't declared or captured. `waitpid` also expects an `int*` as the second argument. [Like this](https://godbolt.org/z/Gj67MGqz9). Btw, if you do like that, the member variable `bool stopped;` seems pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If do not take into account the typo relative to the missing semicolon in this statement

```
job = jobs.erase(job)
                    ^^^
```

and the second typo in this condition

```
if (!job->stopped) {
    ^^^^
```

which should be written like

```
if ( job->stopped) {
```

(that is you need to remove as you wrote all jobs with the set flag `stopped`) your code is correct but is redundant.

You could just write

```
jobs.remove_if( []( const auto &job ) { return job.stopped; } );
```

or

```
jobs.remove_if( []( const JobEntry &job ) { return job.stopped; } );
```

if this statement is called within a member function.

Edit: Here is a demonstrative program that uses your class declarations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <ctime>

typedef int pid_t;

class JobsList {
public:
    class JobEntry {
    public:
        pid_t pid, jid;
        std::string cmd;
        time_t in_time;
        bool stopped;

        JobEntry( int pid, int jid, const std::string &cmd, bool stopped )
            :pid( pid ), jid( jid ), cmd( cmd ), stopped( stopped )
        {}
        // TODO: Add your data members

        bool operator<( JobEntry const &tmp ) const {
            return jid < tmp.jid;
        }

        bool operator==( JobEntry const &tmp ) const {
            return jid == tmp.jid;
        }
    };
    std::list<JobEntry> jobs;
};

int main()
{
    JobsList jobs_list =
    {
        {
            { 1, 1, "first", false },
            { 2, 2, "second", true }
        }
    };

    std::cout << jobs_list.jobs.size() << '\n';
    jobs_list.jobs.remove_if( []( const auto &job ) { return job.stopped; } );
    std::cout << jobs_list.jobs.size() << '\n';
}
```

I only introduced for simplicity this typedef

```
typedef int pid_t;
```

and changed a parameter declaration in the constructor

```
JobEntry( int pid, int jid, const std::string &cmd, bool stopped )
                            ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Sorry but ur code doesn't work, I get: In template: no matching function for call to object of type '(lambda at /Users/me/CLionProjects/OS1_WET/Commands.cpp:305:21)' error occurred here in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::list<JobsList::JobEntry>::remove_if<(lambda at /Users/me/CLionProjects/OS1_WET/Commands.cpp:305:21)>' requested here conversion candidate of type 'void (*)(int &)'

Comment: @john It is not my code that does not work. It is your code that does not work. I do not see your code. So you need to provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @john Here's Vlad's solution adapted to your `waitpid` version that you mentioned in the comments: https://godbolt.org/z/WPsaGjoWq